# Crossfade Animation Does Not Work in Firefox, IE, or Opera

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, opera

I am trying to write a simple CSS crossfade animation that transitions between 4 different images, but it does not work in any version of Firefox (I am testing this on v.30), Internet Explorer, or Opera. It works just fine in Chrome and Safari, though.

I have looked all over and seen similar problems, but sadly no solutions that work. What is very odd is that I had a MUCH more complex crossfade animation that worked and transitioned between images using both ease-in and ease-out and that worked just fine on all browsers. (I may post it for reference later)

I have tried this both with and without the markups for individual browsers with the same results. Also, I heard that the generic markups should always go last, but doing so yields the same result.

**HTML:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="crossfade.css">
 </head>
     <div id="crossfade">
     </div> 
 </html>
```

**CSS:**

```
 #crossfade {
     width: 1000px;
     height: 200px;
     -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
     -webkit-animation: myfirst 30s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
     -moz-animation: myfirst 30s infinite ;
     -o-animation: myfirst 30s infinite;
     -ms-animation: myfirst 30s infinite;
     animation: myfirst 30s infinite;
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
     0%   {background-image:url('images/summerbg1.png');}
     35%  {background-image:url('images/summerbg2.png');}
     75%  {background-image:url('images/summerbg3.png');}
     100% {background-image:url('images/summerbg4.png');}
 }

 @-moz-keyframes myfirst { 
     0%   {background-image:url('images/summerbg1.png');}
     35%  {background-image:url('images/summerbg2.png');}
     75%  {background-image:url('images/summerbg3.png');}
     100% {background-image:url('images/summerbg4.png');}
 }

 @-o-keyframes myfirst { 
     0%   {background-image:url('images/summerbg1.png');}
     35%  {background-image:url('images/summerbg2.png');}
     75%  {background-image:url('images/summerbg3.png');}
     100% {background-image:url('images/summerbg4.png');}
 }

 @-ms-keyframes myfirst { 
     0%   {background-image:url('images/summerbg1.png');}
     35%  {background-image:url('images/summerbg2.png');}
     75%  {background-image:url('images/summerbg3.png');}
     100% {background-image:url('images/summerbg4.png');}
 }

 @keyframes myfirst {
     0%   {background-image:url('images/summerbg1.png');}
     35%  {background-image:url('images/summerbg2.png');}
     75%  {background-image:url('images/summerbg3.png');}
     100% {background-image:url('images/summerbg4.png');}
 }
```

Comment: You could create four separate divs (one for each bg) and fade them in and out with opacity.

Comment: According to MDN background-image is not animatable, so I'm surprised that it works at all in chrome. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

Comment: @RobErskine I will look into doing that and post my results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Rob's advice, here is what I did using figure tags instead of div. It looks almost exactly the same as the animations, but works in IE, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and Safari. (I did not, however, test this on versions of IE earlier than 8).

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="crossfade.css">
</head>

<div id="xfade">

    <figure>
        <img src="Summer/images/summerbg1.png" />
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="Summer/images/summerbg2.png" />
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="Summer/images/summerbg3.png" />
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="Summer/images/summerbg4.png" />
         </figure>

</div>  
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#xfade{
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#xfade figure{
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
#xfade img{
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
}

#xfade figure{
  opacity:0;
}


figure:nth-child(1) {
  animation: xfade 48s 0s infinite;
  -moz-animation: xfade 48s 0s infinite; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: xfade 48s 0s infinite; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-animation: xfade 48s 0s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(2) {
  animation: xfade 48s 12s infinite;
  -moz-animation: xfade 48s 12s infinite; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: xfade 48s 12s infinite; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-animation: xfade 48s 12s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(3) {
  animation: xfade 48s 24s infinite;
  -moz-animation: xfade 48s 24s infinite; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: xfade 48s 24s infinite; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-animation: xfade 48s 24s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(4) {
  animation: xfade 48s 36s infinite;
  -moz-animation: xfade 48s 36s infinite; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: xfade 48s 36s infinite; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-animation: xfade 48s 36s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes xfade{ /* Safari and Chrome */
  0%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

 @-moz-keyframes xfade { 
  0%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

 @-o-keyframes xfade { 
  0%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

 @-ms-keyframes xfade { 
  0%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes xfade{
  0%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```